# run custom shell script '[cp] embed pods frameworks' in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just updated the cocoapods to latest version.
current verison is 1.3.1
After that, I can't archive the project.
Whenever I try to archive the project, I am getting following errors.so I have attached the screenshots.

[image]

Comment: I have the same error...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: What does CP mean?

Answer (score 7):

You can go to `Build Phases` and then to `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`. 
Here remove the script. Also, see the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem!
try updating your keyChain password. For that try following

[Getting this error command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 with xcode 9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409062/getting-this-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-with-xcode)

Hoping it will be helpful

Comment: After update from xCode 9.2 to 9.3 I got this error and the solution was to here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25321/keychain-says-access-to-this-item-is-restricted-after-upgrading-to-lion