# Xcode AFNetworking - Command /bin/sh with exit code 1

Tags: swift, xcode, afnetworking

When I run my project I get this error, i can't understand the problem...

```
Showing Recent Issues
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clubber.build/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.build/Script-6032B42DA46117C50C8623CC.sh
    cd /Users/leo/Documents/Progetti/iOS/Clubber
    /bin/sh -c /Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clubber.build/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.build/Script-6032B42DA46117C50C8623CC.sh

mkdir -p /Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework" "/Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
AFNetworking.framework/
AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
AFNetworking.framework/Info.plist

sent 1305423 bytes  received 70 bytes  2610986.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1305025  speedup is 1.00
Stripped /Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking of architectures: armv7
Code Signing /Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: cana.46@live.it (U698V62S44)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 17E36AAB0AE20D9A471180DEC67D5500DF962DC0  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'
/Users/leo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clubber-ghdadinxjzgblkgllmrradwnzqcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clubber.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to:

- Clean my project
- Delete derived data
- Reinstall my pods
- Set **Build Active architetture** only to **NO** in my POD Project
- I also tried to read a lot of related posts but nothing... -.-

This problem is driving me crazy, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you might have not check the "run the script only when installing"

1. go to the project build folder
2. Select Targets
3. Select Build Phases tab
4. Open Run Script drop-down option
5. **Select Run script only when installing checkbox**

And then clean your project (cmd+shift+k) and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution, for some reasons my login keychan wasn't still valid, this works for me : [Getting this error command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 with xcode 9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409062/getting-this-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-with-xcode)